# new distros cause segmentation fault of old binary

Tags: gcc, compatibility, segmentation-fault

I have an elderly (~1999) and unfortunately commercial graphic program that runs perfectly OK on systems with gcc up to 3.4.6 (CentOS 4.8). However, in all distributions based on gcc 4.* that I've tried, the program fails with "Segmentation fault" (I tried different versions of CenOS, Sebian and SUSE).

There are newer versions of this software (we even have a license) with plenty of new options, so for daily work we're well served. However the old one has this nice option to export a graphic as an x-graphic, whereas the newer versions are only PpenGL-based. Even if x-graphic is ugly (sorry for this adjective) it's much faster if you work over a DSL-line.

The only libraries that were missing during installation were: libXp.so.6, libXmu.so.6 and mesa3. I've installed them without any problems using the standard repository.

I've tried to `strace` the fault but after loading all of the required libraries the program just stops without giving me too much info:

```
open("/lib/libuuid.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\300\17\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=15200, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 17828, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xfffffffff7464000
mmap2(0xf7468000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3) = 0xfffffffff7468000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff7463000
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff7462000
set_thread_area(0xff8de9b4)             = 0
mprotect(0xf746c000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x439000, 8192, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0xf74dc000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xf763f000, 1032192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0xf763f000, 1032192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC) = 0
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

Does anybody have any ideas how to get this program running on the newer distros?

p.s. I do not have sources for it. The advise *Use the source, Luke!!* will not work for me.

p.s.s. For curious people - the software is called gaussview v2

Comment: If you're not compiling from source, surely you mean "glibc" rather than "gcc"? Anyway, what does the core file show?

Comment: @Useless Maybe the distros have been compiled with the `gcc` version they contain?

Comment: Well, the ABI is supposed to be stable and forward-compatible from 3.4, so it seems more likely either to be UB that used to work, or a library version. A core file should be able to clear it up.

Comment: @Useless There is no core file. I thought that it's normal with SIGSEGV. As to the gcc, I meant it. The older system has glibc 2.3.4 When I installed the compatibility libs in the same version on newer distro, I see the same "Segmentation fault". For this reason I referred to gcc version not to libc.

Comment: Can you check the core file limit? (Or just run `ulimit -c unlimited` if you're using bash, and try again)

Comment: can Avogadro (http://avogadro.openmolecules.net/) do the graphical export you need?

Comment: @Useless I did as you asked and core-file was dumped. However I have no idea how to analyse it. There are no debug information in binary.

Comment: @Craig Sanders - nope, I use sometimes avogadro, but problem is with speed of opengl over DSL.

Comment: @Useless I added some debuginfo-rpms however I couldn't find these three libICE-debuginfo, libXp-debuginfo and libuuid-debuginfo. These libs are in base-repo of centos but nothing in debug repo.

Comment: @Kris_R by *OpenGL over DSL* you mean that you are using the application remotely?

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to install an older distribution (CentOS 4, if that's what you're used to) in a [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) and run your application in there. It'll use up a few GB of disk space but it's likely to be a lot less time-consuming than finding a way to make the binary work with current libraries.

I don't have a procedure to offer you to install CentOS in a chroot. The [manual installation instructions](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/ManualInstall) should be a good starting point — skip the part about making the installation bootable and set up a chroot instead. You can use [schroot](http://www.nikhef.nl/~dennisvd/schroot.html) to make this easier ([tutorial](http://le-gall.net/sylvain+violaine/blog/index.php?post/2010/08/26/63-centos-5-chroot-with-schroot)).